# How to use a Liferay service builder jar in other portlets

Tags: service, liferay, jndi, builder

I have a Liferay portal project built using the service builder.  In generating the portlet a jar is also created and I want to use that jar in other portlets.  From posts here and elsewhere the suggested approach is to just place the myPortletName-portlet-services.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the other portlet.  I have also seen where the *-portlet-services.jar is placed in the /lib/ext folder of Tomcat.  I have also read where the liferay-plugin-package.properties should be updated with the dependency.

I have tried each approach and each produces a result that is tantalizingly close to working. The service builder built jar references a jndi/jdbc global resource that is different than the LR database and when a method is invoked from that jar, I receive a "user lacks privilege or object not found:" error (I have posted about this elsewhere).

My hunch is that the jar has some dependencies on Spring/Hibernate that are not being met.  That, or the jndi/jdbc resource isn't "visible" when the jar is placed outside the service builder deployed portal.  In any case, it's obvious that the jar's methods are being found (else the dreaded beanLocator error) so it is now simply a DB connection issue.

The question is: Are there some structural dependencies that are not being met when a jar generated by the service builder is placed outside the originating portal in some other portal?

Comment: Are you saying that you are putting the generated `*-service.jar` outside the liferay portal deployment like say in a separate web-application on the same server or on some other server? Can you clear this part for me? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  If structure like:

Comment: Yes.  The structure is like:
webapps/BaseServicePortal/WEB-INF/lib/*-service.jar
webapps/MyPortal/WEB-INF/lib/*-service.jar

I have also put the *-service.jar in the $TOMCAT-HOME$/lib/ext folder and in all cases the deployment is to the same Tomcat instance

Comment: As per your question, service-builder.jar is having different database than the one that your LR portal is using, correct?
You are calling a method from let say portlet-A and method is in portlet-B-service.jar and you are facing exception as mentioned above.

Is my understanding clear for your query?

Comment: Yes.  The database is on a MSSQL server and the LR DB is MySQL.  All our services built from Service Builder, essentially all DB I/O to MSSQL, is through one SB built portlet.  Those services are called from other LifeRay portlets AND servlets installed on the same TC server.  I haven't revisited this issue for quite some time but I may be dealing with it again if we move to the latest LR version and move to Tomcat rather than Glassfish

Answer (score 0):

For use a Liferay service builder jar in other portlets
Try:

1. create [ServiceLocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) placed in jar in lib of Tomcat (or other aplication server).
2. set your bean from service builder to service locator by setter as static field in spring context (setter must set static field)
3. Next implement bean that will use bean from service locator and will delagate calls

   - simply pass your bean from service builder through class static field placed in tomcat lib (visible everywhere)
   - place required interfaces also in jar in lib